# problema con mi navegador mozilla firefox, no puedo ocupar "time" ni "date", implementar javascript para corregir este problema

Tags: php, javascript, html5, codeigniter

necesito poner la hora en un input, en crome me aparecen unas flechitas dentro del input para agregar la hora, pero en mozilla no me aparece, como puedo implementar esto con javascript para que me funciones en mozilla, este es mi codigo.

```
<?php
$actual=strftime( "%Y-%m-%d", time() );
?>

<script type="text/javascript">



function Mostrar() {
  document.getElementById("FormArchivo").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("BtnO").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("Archivo").value=1;
  document.getElementById("Form").action="../cargar_archivo";
   document.getElementById("Btn1").style.display = 'none';
}

function Ocultar() {
    document.getElementById("FormArchivo").style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById("BtnO").style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById("Archivo").value=0;
      document.getElementById("Form").action="cargar_archivo";
  document.getElementById("Btn1").style.display = "inline";
}

function virtual(){
 if (document.getElementById('Virtual').checked 
||document.getElementById('Mixta').checked   ) {
 document.getElementById("LUbicacion").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("Ubicacion").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('Ubicacion').value = " ";   

  }else{
       document.getElementById("LUbicacion").style.display = 'inline';
       document.getElementById("Ubicacion").style.display = 'inline';
  }
}

function dias(){
  if (document.getElementById('MDias').checked) {
document.getElementById("LFecha").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("Fecha").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('Fecha').value = ""; 
document.getElementById("HoraI").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('HoraI').value = " "; 
document.getElementById("HoraF").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('HoraF').value = " "; 
document.getElementById("LHoraI").style.display = 'none';  
document.getElementById("LHoraF").style.display = 'none'; 
  }else{
       document.getElementById("LFecha").style.display = 'inline';
       document.getElementById("Fecha").style.display = 'inline';
       document.getElementById("HoraI").style.display = 'inline';
       document.getElementById("HoraF").style.display = 'inline';
       document.getElementById("LHoraI").style.display = 'inline';  
       document.getElementById("LHoraF").style.display = 'inline'; 
  }

}


  function mail() {
var tutor = document.getElementById("idtutor").value;
document.getElementById("email").value = tutor;
  }


</script>

<div class="panel-body">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <form  action="../insertarAdm" method="POST"  id="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">  
    <label for="Nombre">Tutor: <span id="asterisco">* </span></label>
       <!--<input type="hidden" name="Nombre" <?php //echo "value=\"".$this->tank_auth->get_user_id()."\""; ?> >--> 
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <select class="form-control" name="idtutor" onchange="mail()" id="idtutor" style="width:300px">
    <?php 
     $this->db->order_by("Apellido", "asc");
      $mas=$this->db->get('users');
      if($mas->num_rows() > 0){
        if($mas != FALSE){
          foreach($mas->result() as $ma){
            if($ma->username != $username && $ma->activated != 0){



              echo "<option value='".$ma->id."'>".$ma->Apellido." ".$ma->username."</option>"; 

              }
            }
          }
        }
      ?>
      </select>
  </div>
  </div>
<br>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">  
        <label for="Nombre">Email: <span id="asterisco">* </span></label>
       <input type="hidden" name="Nombre" <?php echo "value=\"".$this->tank_auth->get_user_id()."\""; ?> > 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control" name="email"  id="email"  style="width:300px" disabled>
    <?php 
    $this->db->order_by("Apellido", "asc");
    $mas=$this->db->get('users');
    if($mas->num_rows() > 0){
    if($mas != FALSE){
      foreach($mas->result() as $ma){
        if($ma->username != "Administrador" && $ma->activated != 0 ){
          //if($ma->username !=Administrador $ma->activated != 0){
              echo "<option value='".$ma->id."'>".$ma->email."</option>"; 

              }
            }
          }
        }
              ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
    <br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="Carrera">Carrera: </label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control" name="opcarrera" id="Carrera" style="width:300px">
                    <OPTION VALUE="Informática">Informática</OPTION>
                    <OPTION VALUE="Redes y Servicios de Cómputo">Redes y Servicios de Cómputo</OPTION>
                    <OPTION VALUE="Tecnologías Computacionales">Tecnologías Computacionales</OPTION>
                    <OPTION VALUE="Ingenieria de Software">Ingenieria de Software</OPTION> 
                    <OPTION VALUE="Ciencias y Técnias Estadísticas">Ciencias y Técnias Estadísticas</OPTION>  
                    </SELECT> 
                </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label for="Numtuto">Tutoría:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                     <select class="form-control" name="optuto" id="Carrera" style="width:300px">
                    <OPTION VALUE="1">Tutoría 1</OPTION>
                    <OPTION VALUE="2">Tutoría 2</OPTION>
                    <OPTION VALUE="3">Tutoría 3</OPTION>
                    <OPTION VALUE="4">Tutoría especial</OPTION>  
                    </SELECT> 
                </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label id="LModalidad">Modalidad: <span id="asterisco">* </span></label>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="radio">
                    <label id="LPresencial"><input type="radio"  onclick="virtual()" name="opModalidad" value="presencial" id="presencial" required >Presencial</label>
                    <label id="LVirtuaal"><input type="radio" onclick="virtual()" name="opModalidad" value="virtual" id="virtual">Virtual</label>
                    <label id="LMixta"><input type="radio"  onclick="virtual()" name="opModalidad" value="mixta" id="mixta">Mixta</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label id="LAtencion">Periodo Atención: <span id="asterisco">* </span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="radio">
                    <label id="LDia"><input type="radio" onclick="dias()" value="un sólo día" name="opAtencion" id="Dia" checked>Un solo día</label>
                    <label id="LMDias"><input type="radio"  onclick="dias()" value="más de un día" name="opAtencion" id="MDias">Más de un día (Capture toda la información necesaria en el campo Notas, o bien, agrege un archivo)</label>
                </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label for="Ubicacion" id="LUbicacion">Lugar:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Ubicacion" id="Ubicacion" value="" maxlength="50" placeholder="lugar de tutoria màximo 50 caracteres"  style="width:300px" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label id="LFecha">Fecha:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="date" class="tcal" name="Fecha" id="Fecha" value=""  style="width:300px">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label id="LHoraI">Hora Inicio:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="HoraI" id="HoraI" value=" " style="width:300px" title="Formato 24 hras" >
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label id="LHoraF">Hora Final:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="time" class="form-control" name="HoraF" id="HoraF" value=" " style="width:300px" title="Formato 24 hras">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                    <label for="comment">Notas:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="Nota" id="Nota" maxlength="150" rows="3" placeholder="Máximo 150 caracteres" ></textarea>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div id="FormArchivo" style='display:none;' id="FormArchivo" style='display:none;' aling="center">
                        <input type="text" name="Archivo" style="visibility:hidden"  id="Archivo" value=0/>


                     <h3>Solo acepta archivos PDF y que sea menor a 5 mb</h3>
                     <input type="file" name="mi_archivo" >
                    </div>
                    <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6    ">
                        <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" name="Insertar" id="Guardar" value="Guardar Horario"/>
                        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" onclick="Mostrar()" id="Btn1" value="Subir horario mediante archivo"/>
                        <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" onclick="Ocultar()" id="BtnO" style='display:none;' value="Cancelar"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: las tags de html5 no son soportados por todos los navegadores en desktop, pero si quieres simular el control que ves en chrome, puedes utilizar un plugin de jquery [ejemplo](http://ericjgagnon.github.io/wickedpicker/)

Answer (score 1):

Firefox aún no soporta dichos tipos de input de HTML5.

Puedes verlo en caniuse
http://caniuse.com/input-datetime/embed/